# Infer correct data type from query string parameters

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to infer the types from parameters of a query string (using Javascript).

Example URL:

```
http://example.com/some/path/here/?someString=Hey&someNumber=20
```

I've used a couple of packages (`query-string` and `simple-query-string`) like so:

```
queryString.parse(request.url)
```

Where `request.url` is the url above.  This gives the following:

```
{
    "someString":"Hey",
    "someNumber":"20"
}
```

Where `someNumber` above is type `string`. The desired result is:

```
{
    "someString":"Hey",
    "someNumber":20
}
```

Where `someNumber` is type `integer`.

The reason I want `integer` type is because I am performing JSONSchema validation on the parameters which specify the types which are allowed per named parameter.

I am aware that I can cast these instances, but I'd prefer if it was available from a package since it feels a lot like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: There is no JSON anywhere in what you've posted ?

Comment: All http query params are strings. You will have to check if the values of the query params can be parsed into numbers yourself.

Comment: @adeneo looks like I had missed some commas (updated), unless you're referring to something else.

Comment: Unless the package specifically allows it you're going to have to do the Type Casting yourself.

Comment: Actually, what I was referring to, was that the middleware you're using, takes the querystring and creates a valid object from it, there is no JSON anywhere, other than you wanting to validate an object as JSON ?

Comment: Yes sry for any confusion @adeneo, you're right and thanks for pointing it out, will update the title.  This question is more about the ability to parse out the right type so that I can use it down the line. I understand that query parameters are passed as strings, but surely I am not the only person who wants to infer the type of the parameters during parsing.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. You could potentially add more/different regex tests to supplement the simple number check that's in place now (for instance, detect dates, dollar amounts, telephone numbers etc.)

```js
var exampleurl = "http://example.com/some/path/here/?someString=Hey&someNumber=20"

function getQueryStringData(url){
  var data = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
    numberRgx = /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
  
  return data.reduce(function(obj, t){
    var pair = t.split('='),
        key = pair[0],
        val = pair[1]
    
    obj[key] = numberRgx.test(val) ? parseFloat(val) : val
    return obj
  }, {})
}


var obj = getQueryStringData(exampleurl)

console.log(obj)

document.getElementById('output').textContent = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the regex tests are a better alternative to what I was thinking of. It still seems like parsing query string parameters directly into inferred types is a not-too-uncommon operation that should be solved already in a library.

Comment: True. Also, that regex was wrong, it'd fail on a single digit number. It should have been `\d+(\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method of typecasting an object's properties. if the string itself is one of the special matches in the expression, JSON.parse it, else try Number, else leave it as-is.

```
  function cast (o) {
    var result = {};
    for(var prop in o) { if(o.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      var val = o[prop];
      if (typeof val === 'object') return o[prop] = cast(val);
      result[prop] = /^(true|false|null|undefined)$/.test(val) ? JSON.parse(val) : Number(val) || val;
    }}
    return result;
  }
```

`cast( { a: '123', b: 'null', c: 'abc' } )` returns `{a: 123, b: null, c: "abc"}`